# Failure cases of pthread_cond_init

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

The `pthread_cond_init()` function shall fail if:

> EAGAIN The system lacked the necessary resources (other than memory)  to  initialize  another  condition variable.

From the man page of `pthread_cond_init()`.

What can be the other resources the quote is talking about?

Comment: Probably any other implementation-dependent native resources eg. handles, non-paged pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a limit on number of conditional variables per thread.